# iphone development: one button two actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, button, action

In my application I have a button and when it is pressed, lets say "touch Up inside" another view is opened. well my question is, how can I do two actions? I mean, when I pressing the button I want something to do(like hiding the button or changing the image of the button), and when I stop pressing I want to be navigated to the another view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
[yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Now selectors are:

```
-(IBAction)touchUp :(id)sender{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
  [btn setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; 
}

-(IBAction)touchDown :(id)sender{

  //Navigate here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to 'do something' when 'pressing', then just hook up 'Touch Down'

Answer (score 1):

The class that is the delegate for the button needs to track the state, and manage that state through the events that can occur (a state machine).  Use instance variables to track the state.

When you handle the button action, the code should determine what state it is in, and make any changes necessary to move to the next state.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your code to IBActions. Then like the actions through the interface builder to different touch events.

Code:

```
[yourUIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventXXXXX];
```

There are a lot of events you can link your UIButton to:

> UIControlEventTouchDown
>      UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat
>      UIControlEventTouchDragInside
>      UIControlEventTouchDragOutside
>      UIControlEventTouchDragEnter
>      UIControlEventTouchDragExit
>      UIControlEventTouchUpInside
>      UIControlEventTouchUpOutside
>      UIControlEventTouchCancel

Ref:[UIControl Apple Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use different actions for different ControlEvents

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown] ;    
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] ;
```